# How to fix textarea selection issue inside ionic application?

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, ionic-framework

I have a simple textarea:

```
<textarea></textarea>
```

When I enter multiple lines and then press backspace iOS starts deleting letters then words. When it switches to "words mode" it shows selection, which is lagging behind and misplaced. It's better to see once:

http://i.imgur.com/e1GC8PI.gifv

This behavior happens on real iPhone 5 device too. It cannot be reproduced from regular Safari.

How this can be fixed?

Comment: can you share your `$ionicPlatform.ready` in `.run` in app.js ?

Comment: @Webruster it's regular ionic blank starter app: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-blank/blob/master/js/app.js All I did is just added `textarea` inside `ion-content` here: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-blank/blob/master/index.html#L30

Comment: In that app.js you already added this `cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);` please try to add this one and see if it works `cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);`

Comment: @Webruster double checked - it doesn't fix the problem

Comment: i missed this point also add after the `$ionicPlatform.ready` `window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard`

Comment: i changed the ion-content like below after changing my $ionicplatform.ready `<ion-content overflow-scroll="false">   <textarea name="test" type="text" rows="8" cols="3" placeholder="Details" class="text-area"> </textarea></ion-content>`

Comment: @Webruster after your changes do you see the bug fixed? Are you using iOS? I don't see how your suggested changes fix the problem.

Comment: i dont say bug got fixed but i would say that i am unable to repro your issue, by following above procedure

Comment: @Webruster how do you test it? Do you use iOS Emulator with iOS keyboard? I can't reproduce the bug using my laptop keyboard. Only happens on real device or when device's keyboard is used in emulator.

Comment: i used using the real device and my device is iphone 6.(added to it, i buiid my code using visual studio 2015)

Answer (score 0):

this was caused by autocorrect on iOS, simple add following to the textarea could solve problem:

```
<textarea autocorrect="off"></textarea>
```

Comment: tell me a bit more about your environment, i can not reproduce your issue, a bit curious about your visual studio 2015 build!

Comment: I'm using OSX, 10.10.5, just command line and regular xCode simulator